# How to actually measure/compute data quality

Tags: validation, data-quality

I need to come up with data quality metrics for a project and how to measure them. I've been googling and reading and I understood that you can 'measure' the quality of data using the 6 dimensions (Accuracy, completeness, uniqueness, validity, timeliness and consistency).

For Accuracy, the *'ratio of data to errors'* metric can be used. For Completeness the *'number of empty values'* metric can be used and for Timeliness the *'data time to value'* metric can be used (formulas of each below):

**ratio to errors:** tot nr of errors (errors = missing, incomplete or redundant entires) / tot nr of rows

**nr of empty fields:** tot nr of empty fields/NULLs in data set

**data time to value** = time data received - time data requested

For **uniqueness**, **validity**, and **consistency** however I did not find a formula. Can someone please help me? I've been googling forever, but I didn't manage to find concrete examples of how the above dimensions are actually measured. Thanks a lot! :-)